# Prove that kernel has strict inclusions for minimum polynomial x^m

Tags: linear-algebra, minimal-polynomials

Let T : V → V have minimum polynomial $m_T (x) = x^m$

Show that we have strict inclusions $0 ⊂ ker(T)⊂ ker(T^2)⊂ ... ⊂ ker(T^m)=V$

My idea is to do a proof by contradiction: suppose, for a contradiction, that we have an equality, and then hopefully getting a lower degree annilating polynomial, a contradiction.

However, I'm not having much success so would appreciate some help, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Since the minimal polynomial of $T$ is $x^{m}$,then there is some $z$ such that $T^{m-1}(z)\neq 0$, otherwise $T^{m-1}$ would be identically zero,i.e $T$ is annihilated by $x^{m-1}$,which contradicts the fact that its minimal polynomial is $x^{m}$.now, u can remark that for every $1\leq k\leq m$, $T^{m-k}z$ belongs to $Ker T^{k}$ but doesn't belong to $Ker T^{k-1}$ (by convention $Ker T^{0}=\{0\}$

Answer (score 0):

Denote by $j$ the smallest integer verifying $\ker T^j = \ker T^{j+1}$. Note that the latter is well-defined as $m$ verifies the previous equation. In particular, $j\le m$, our goal is to show that $j= m$, this will exactly translate the strict inclusions you want to prove. An easy induction allows us to see that $\ker T^j = \ker T^{j+p}$ for all $p\ge 0$. In particular we have
$$
\ker T^j = \ker T^m = V.
$$
This shows that the polynomial $x^j$ vanishes on $T$. Since the minimal polynomial of $T$ is $x^m$, we have $m\le j$ which shows that $j=m$.

Answer (score 0):

Consider mathematical induction
0 ⊂ kerT:
The inclusion 0 ⊂ kerT is trivial, as the zero vector is always in the kernel of any linear transformation.

kerT ⊂ ker(T^2):
Let v be an element in kerT, meaning T(v) = 0. We want to show that v is also in ker(T^2), which means T^2(v) = T(T(v)) = T(0) = 0. Since T(0) = 0, v is indeed in ker(T^2), and the inclusion holds.

Continue this process for ker(T^(i)) ⊂ ker(T^(i+1)) for i = 2, 3, ..., m-1:
Given that ker(T^(i)) ⊂ ker(T^(i+1)), we can use the same reasoning as in step 2. If v is in ker(T^(i)), then T^(i)(v) = T^(i-1)(T(v)) = T^(i-1)(0) = 0, which means v is also in ker(T^(i+1)). So the inclusions hold for all i from 2 to m-1.

To prove the final inclusion, ker(T^(m-1)) ⊂ ker(T^m) = V:
Since the minimum polynomial of T is mT(x) = x^m, it means that T^m(v) = 0 for all vectors v in V. Therefore, ker(T^(m-1)) is a subspace of ker(T^m) = V. In other words, the kernel of T^(m-1) is a proper subset of the kernel of T^m.

So, we've shown that all the inclusions are strict as stated:

0 ⊂ kerT ⊂ ker(T^2) ⊂ ... ⊂ ker(T^(m-1)) ⊂ ker(T^m) = V.